# Converting set of Shapefiles to OpenStreetMap (OSM) file?

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, convert, merge

How can I convert a set of ShapeFiles to an [OSM file](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML)?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with JOSM + OpenData plugin. With this extension JOSM can open SHP (4326) than you can save it as OSM file

Comment: For repeated needs ogr2osm is more easy to use in scripts http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Ogr2osm.

Comment: I tried to use the OpenData plugin to convert a 600mb shape file but it looks like there is a memory leak in the plugin.

Comment: Actually, turned out that it required 20GB of memory to open aforementioned file. JOSM became unresponsive, laggy at best, after it finally processed my .shp file. This is an unacceptable tool / method to convert .shp files into .osm files.

Comment: I agree with @skubski; JOSM is incredibly sluggish ans slow and sucks memory. Another tools should be used.

Answer (score 2):

shp-to-osm.jar has a simple configuration file to translate shapefile attributes to SOM key-value pairs

https://github.com/iandees/shp-to-osm

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Shp-to-osm.jar

Answer (score 1):

On the [OSM Wiki Import Page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Import/Shapefile) you find an exhautive list of tools, that can convert shapefiles to an OSM file (All above mentioned tools are included).